# How can i set the Object Path in typo3 from db

Tags: database, typo3

I'm trying to find a way in typoScript to render a view, from its name that comes from the db...

Currently, I now do it in the Object path option in typo3 control Panel... I wonder if I can get this data from the db

Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you post some code or provide more details?

Comment: PLease, give us some more insight or your own solution if you found it.

Comment: I have the object path inside a whole html code, I must find this string and render it

I was thinking is something like 

`<html>
    <body>
        ...
        <OBJECTPATH>
           lib.myObjectPath
        </OBJECTPATH>
        ...
    </body>
</html>`

But I dont find a way from typo script, to find this tag and render it with out parse all the html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find a typo3 extension
`TypoScript code (typoscript_code)` that allow me to render a t3 from the database.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, getting any value from the db and render it, try this:

```
lib.customValue = CONTENT
lib.customValue {
    table = tx_any_table
    select {
        pidInList = 999
        where = some_field = 999
        max = 1
    }
    renderObj >
    renderObj = COA_INT
    renderObj {
        10 = TEXT
        10.field = any_field
    }
}
```

But I assume that the *string* you now have represents a (part of a) *typoscript object*, and you need the value of this object to be rendered? Hope I (or someone else) can add some more info for that soon.

Comment: The idea is that I have a tt_content in its table like an html code

Inside this code, (that I generate outside typo3), I must add a lib.whatever and then represents it with the select

I could add this text in any text/tag or whatever I need... but I dont find any way else than parse all html from typo3

Comment: To be honest: I don't know how to do that. Or I don't understand what you need.